# Vertical RecyclerView with snapping full screen cards

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-scrollview

I'd like to have a list of cards that each fill almost the full screen (80% vertical).  The middle card will always be centered after scrolling. I'd like to be able to have a snap scroll where anytime I flick up it goes to the next card and same thing when flicking down (unless I don't scroll far enough and then it just bounces same card back to middle). It should feel like a snappy scroll that could only go 1 page at a time. I'm having trouble figuring out if this should be some sort of viewpager or recyclerview or just just a scrollview. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  To me it seems like this is the same behavior that a viewpager has expect horizontal.  Any suggestions of how to implement?

Answer (score 0):

```
SnapHelper helper = new LinearSnapHelper();
helper.attachToRecyclerView(yourRecyclerView);
```

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value